How can I capture a stream from the stage with Konva React (konva-react)?
I would like to capture a stream from a Konva Stage.
Before I used regular <canvas ref={canvasRef} />. After let canvas = canvasRef.current I was able to capture a stream with let mediaStream: MediaStream = canvas.captureStream(30).
Does anyone know how I can achieve the same result using konva-react?
I already tried <Stage ref={stageRef}>...</Stage> and then let canvas = stageRef.current.getStage().toCanvas(), but apparently it doesn't work.
ps. I null-checked before ref.current, so neither canvasRef nor stageRef can be null
Thanks for your help!

On konva, Stage doesn't have its own canvas. But a Layer have it.
<Layer ref={layerRef}>...</Layer>

const canvas = layerRef.current.getNativeCanvasElement();
const mediaStream = canvas.captureStream(30)

